# What should I do to terminate the current command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, terminal

I sshed to a server and pasted a long command and it turned to the following:

[image]

What mode is it now? Why can't I terminate it with `Ctrl+C` nor `Ctrl+]` nor `Ctrl+[`?

Comment: The terminal is currently waiting on more input. I don't know if there is an exact name for this, but it sometimes happens to me when I input a command incorrectly or it wasn't fully complete. For example, missing the closing `"` when doing a git commit. To get out of it, try Ctrl+Z.

Comment: @DrZoo when I type `if` and hit enter to get the continuation prompt in bash, Ctrl-C gives me my regular prompt back while Ctrl-Z does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can press `~.` to terminate your ssh connnection. You can check out the "ESCAPE CHARACTERS" section in `man ssh` for more escape characters.